# main(int argc, char *argv[]) giving strange results for * as command line argument

Tags: c, command

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

This simple program compiled with gcc

```
saad@saad-700Z3C-700Z5C:~/KANDR$ ./a.out 
1
saad@saad-700Z3C-700Z5C:~/KANDR$ ./a.out 13 432
3
saad@saad-700Z3C-700Z5C:~/KANDR$ ./a.out 13 432 + 
4
saad@saad-700Z3C-700Z5C:~/KANDR$ ./a.out 13 432 +  *
112
saad@saad-700Z3C-700Z5C:~/KANDR$ ^C
```

Why does the last command return 112, when i have `*` as command line argument?

Comment: You could have debugged this for yourself by modifying the code to print the arguments as well as argc.  Then you'd have seen what the trouble is.  (`for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);`).  Learning to think about how you could find out what's going on is a key part of learning to program, and using print statements is one way to do it.  The primary alternative is to run the program in a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Because the shell expands the `*` to the file names in the current directory. To make sure try like this

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i)
    fprintf(stdout, "arg[%zu]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
```

It's exactly how `rm *` would remove all files in the current directory.

Comment: Escape it, like `\*` or perhaps `'*'`.

Comment: thing is, when i have * in the command line argument, the argc count is coming as the total no of files in the current directory plus the no of command line arguments, how can i pass * as command line argument rather than the whole list of files?

Answer (score 1):

The * in shell extract all the files in the current directory and put into the command line arguments list.
So the argc coming 112. If you want to pass the "*" to the program you can use the below methods.

"*" (or) '*' (or) \*